# URL display:none;

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this code, for some reason when I try to access it with a link (http://127.0.0.1:5501/111.html?textarea=2&p=2) the textarea part remains the same, I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

When I open the link I want to see textarea 2 and p 2 visible, the rest should be hidden.
Here is the code in case someone from the forum can help:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylechat.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Support</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1022.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">

      <!-- nav -->

<div class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="logo" href="./index.html">Ho<span>me</span></a>
    </div> 
</div>

      <!-- nav -->

      <!-- info -->
<div class="textinfo">
  <p class="menus" id="dsk1"><span>AAA:</span><br>
    One:<br><br>
  <a href="#">1. test</a><br>
  <a href="#">2. test</a><br></p>

</div>

<div class="textinfo">
  <p class="menus" id="dsk2"><span>AAA:</span><br>
    Two:<br><br>
  <a href="#">1. test</a><br>
  <a href="#">2. test</a><br></p>

</div>

     <!-- info -->

        <!-- text -->
  <div class="textniz">
    <textarea id="myInput1" class="one" name="myInput1" readonly>
One
One
One</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="textniz">
    <textarea id="myInput2" class="two" name="myInput2" readonly>
Two
Two
Two</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="textniz">
    <textarea id="myInput3" class="three" name="myInput3" readonly>
Three
Three
Three</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="textniz">
    <textarea id="myInput4" class="four" name="myInput4" readonly>
Four
Four
Four</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="textniz">
    <textarea id="myInput5" class="five" name="myInput5" readonly>
Five
Five
Five</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="textniz">
    <textarea id="myInput6" class="six" name="myInput6" readonly>
Six
Six
Six</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="textniz">
    <textarea id="myInput7" class="seven" name="myInput7" readonly>
Seven
Seven
Seven</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="textniz">
    <textarea id="myInput8" class="eight" name="myInput8" readonly>
Eight
Eight
Eight</textarea>
  </div>

        <!-- text -->

     <!-- scr -->

  <div class="scrn" id="scrn">
    <img src="/Screenshot_1.png" alt="" class="image1"></img>
    <img src="/Screenshot_2.png" alt="" class="image2"></img>
    <img src="/Screenshot_3.png" alt="" class="image3"></img>
    <img src="/Screenshot_5.png" alt="" class="image4"></img>
  </div>

       <!-- scr -->

    <!-- button -->

    <button onclick="showscr(1)" id="scr1" class="scron1"></button>  
    <button onclick="showscr(2)" id="scr2" class="scron2"></button>  


    <button onclick="Copytextfunction(1)" id="menucopy1" class="menucopy1"></button>
    <button onclick="Copytextfunction(2)" id="menucopy2" class="menucopy2"></button>
    <button onclick="Copytextfunction(3)" id="menucopy3" class="menucopy3"></button>
    <button onclick="Copytextfunction(4)" id="menucopy4" class="menucopy4"></button>
    <button onclick="Copytextfunction(5)" id="menucopy5" class="menucopy5"></button>
    <button onclick="Copytextfunction(6)" id="menucopy6" class="menucopy6"></button>
    <button onclick="Copytextfunction(7)" id="menucopy7" class="menucopy7"></button>
    <button onclick="Copytextfunction(8)" id="menucopy8" class="menucopy8"></button>
  </div>

      <!-- button -->

    <!-- script -->

<script>
// Get textarea from url parameters
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let textarea = urlParams.get('textarea')

function show(textarea) {
  for (let check = 1; check <= 8; check++) {
    document.getElementById('myInput' + check).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('menucopy' + check).style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById('myInput' + textarea).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('menucopy' + textarea).style.display = "block";
}

let p = urlParams.get('p')

function show(p) {
  for (let check = 1; check <= 2; check++) {
    document.getElementById('dsk' + check).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dsk' + check).style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById('dsk' + p).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('dsk' + p).style.display = "block";
}


function Copytextfunction(textarea) {
  var value = document.getElementById('myInput' + textarea).value;
  var copyText = document.createElement("textarea");
  copyText.value = value;
  copyText.style.position = "fixed";
  copyText.style.top = "-1000vh";
  document.body.append(copyText);
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log(value);
  copyText.remove();
}

// Run the hide function with the textarea number from parameters
if (textarea) {
  show(textarea);
}

if (p) {
  show(p);
}
</script>

    <!-- script -->
</body>
```

Comment: You can't use the same name `show()` for two different functions. The second one replaces the first one. Give them different names.